# Project navigator in Xcode does not show a bin (bin/data) folder

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

It might be a simple question.
I needed shader files for my project, then put them in the "/bin/data/" folder.

However, when I opened the project in Xcode, the project navigator does not show the "bin" folder.
[image: path diagram]
[image: project navigator screenshot]

I could write these files with another editor, but what I want to do is to edit them in Xcode just as same as C++ files in the "src" folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked this question on the OF forum only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was really simple.
Right-clicking on the project navigator is the solution (at least one of them).

After right-clicking, the popup has an option "Add files to *your project*", which is just what I was looking for.